# Bug in xcode? Problem with using PNG's in UIImageView

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, copy-paste

Just a small warning for the ones of you who work with a lot of images.

Today I was copying (drag n drop) a lot of PNG images into my xcode project (I'm using 3.2.3). Half way through the copying xcode stopped because there was already a file with the same name. No problem. Deselected that file and copied the rest. All seemed fine.

Later on when I should set an image for a UIImageView with this piece of code

```
[backgroundView initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Wallpaper.png"]];
```

I noticed that only some of the images worked. The rest only showed a blank screen. After some investigation I found that all the images where the copy was interrupted did not work. Once I deleted them and copied them in again it worked.

Has anyone else seen this?

Something to report to Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is simply because the copy operation went wrong and only a weak link remained in the Resource folder. Not a bug to report